# Ping through a virtual machine

Tags: routing, linux

I need help for a little test I am doing with virtual machines (KVM Virt-manager).

I have created 4 VM running Ubuntu Server with static configuration (see schema) linking one VM to the next.

I can ping the closest machines to the VM who's pinging but I cant ping the one who's not directly linked to the VM.
I added the route to rochefort using orval as gateway but still din't work.

> route add -net 172.16.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.1.2

From chimay:

> ping 172.16.1.2 # (orval) works!
>
> ping 172.16.4.4 # (westmalle) works !
>
> **ping 172.16.2.3** # (rochefort) Doesn't work !!!

Example: **chimay** can ping **orval** and **westmalle** but not **rochefort**
[image: Schema]

I have already done the same thing with physical machines and it works so trying to get why it doesn't work with Virtual Maniches.

Thanks in advance for your help !

**EDIT:**

All route:Chimay - Orval - Rochefort - Westmalle

[image]

Comment: Typo "ping 172.26.4.4 # (westmalle) works !"  should be 172.16.4.4

Comment: Please provide # "ip route show" for each of the vm's.

Comment: Yes sorry it's 172.16.4.4. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your conf, and see between your gateways and static routes.

Firts: chimay can ping orval and westmalle because it is directly connected, but, once the request arrives from HOST to chimay, then it is sended to orval and westmalle(you can see it on a sniffer), but the thing is that orval and westmalle do not know where is located HOST(IP 192.168.122.1).

I think you need to add an static route on orval like this

```
(route add -net 192.168.122.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.1.1)
```

and on westmalle

```
(route add -net 192.168.122.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.4.1)
```

The same i think happens from chimay to reach rochefort:

```
You need to set 2 gateways on chimay, and one of then like DEFAULT route, 172.16.1.2 and 172.16.4.4
```

Then, the only thing you need to do is to declare is the gateways and a DEFAULT route on rocheford to reach chimay and HOST and so on, eg: 172.16.2.2 or 172.16.3.4

Comment: Oh you saved me. I think that it was the problem, packets succed to reach rochefort but couldn't go back. Adding the route to HOST, I succed to ping all VMs from chimay. But Idk why HOST route was needed while I ping from chimay... a VM mechanism ? Anyway thank you, I will read a bit about it.

Comment: Oh thanks. About your question: HOST and chimay share a network, 192.168.122.0/24 i guess, but, i think, your default gateway(HOST gateway) go somewhere to reach internet, or another network on your place, or something else. HOST must not know how to reach the network in your Virtural Enviroment, it only knows how to reach 192.168.122.0 ´cause is directly connected, but nothing more. That´s the reason why you need to configure the routes on HOST.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu(Linux) doesn't perform gateway functions aka forward IP packets by default.

You must explicitly tell the system to do so >> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

This guide should help you:
http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/

My hunch is that on your physical topology you already made that change.

Comment: Already tried that enabling ip forwarding but didn't change a thing. I think that ip forwarding will be useful only when leaving that network for an other. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the host(rochfort) you are pinging (from chimay) does not know how to return packets.

> I added the route to rochefort using orval as gateway but still din't work.
>   route add -net 172.16.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.1.2

On **rochefort** add the route

```
ip route add default via 172.16.2.2
```

or

```
ip route add 172.16.1.0/24 via 172.16.2.2
```

On **chimey** add the route

```
ip route ad 172.16.2.0/24 via 172.16.1.2
```

Comment: Edited the post with all routes. Still can't join a VM not directly connected :/